# Хочу сложить массив. Но только при помощи цикла for

Tags: php

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,];

       //Старался сделать по-разному и через функцию коунт, но получается не то.
       // я хочу только вернуть результат '15'


for ($array = 0; $array < 15; $array++); 
echo $array;
```

Comment: Почитайте про цикл [for](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php) и не задавайте больше подобных вопросов

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно получить сумму всех элементов массива? Цикл for (и не только он) нужен для того чтобы выполнять какой-то код какое-то количество раз, и информацию об этом самом количестве и условиях прекращения цикла вы и должны передавать. Вы же, делаете что-то странное. В начале присваиваете массиву 0, затем используете массив в качестве счетчика..

Если вам нужен именно for, то это можно сделать так:

```
// Массив
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
// Сумма всего массива    
$sum = 0;
// Повторять от 0 до кол-ва элементов массива
for($i = 0; i < count($array); i++)
{
   // Прибавлять к сумме i-ый элементы массива
   $sum = $sum + $array[i];
}

// Вывод суммы
echo $sum;
```

Вы также можете использовать более удобный foreach.

```
// Массив
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
// Сумма всего массива    
$sum = 0;
// Пройтись по всему массиву, где key это индекс текущего элемента а value значение
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
   // Прибавлять к сумме значение очередного элемента
   $sum = $sum + $value;
}

// Вывод суммы
echo $sum;
```